# Change cursor shape for 1 second (time duration)

Tags: qt, qml

I have a mouse area.

```
MouseArea {
    id: viewportMouseArea
    // ...
}
```

On receiving a signal, I change cursor [shape](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#CursorShape-enum):

```
onStatusChanged: {
    viewportMouseArea.cursorShape = (myScene.status == MyScene.StatusForbidden) ? Qt.ForbiddenCursor : Qt.ArrowCursor
}
```

The above logic works fine.

I intend change the logic, so that when a signal is received, I change cursor shape for **1 second**, and then after **1 second**, fall back to default cursor shape. Something like this pseudo code:

```
onStatusChanged: {
    if ( myScene.status == MyScene.StatusForbidden ) {
        for-1-second-do:
            viewportMouseArea.cursorShape = Qt.ForbiddenCursor
        After-1-second-do:
            viewportMouseArea.cursorShape = Qt.ArrowCursor // default cursor shape
    }
}
```

What is the best practice to do so?

Comment: Use a Timer ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the **1-second** cursor shape change, using [Timer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html) suggested by @eyllanesc. It works fine:

```
MyScene {
    id: myScene

    onStatusChanged: {
        if ( myScene.Status === MyScene.StatusForbidden ) {
            viewportMouseArea.cursorShape = Qt.ForbiddenCursor
            timerForbidden.restart()
        }
    }

    property Timer timer: Timer {
        id: timerForbidden
        interval: 1000 // milliseconds
        running: false
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: { // triggered() signal is emitted when the Timer times out.

            viewportMouseArea.cursorShape = Qt.ArrowCursor // Default cursor shape
        }
    }
}
```